# How to read an XML loaded from a URL?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to load the Forex Feed from an XML stored at http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml. I followed the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647356/using-forex-feed-from-xml-in-as3/14648024#14648024) question. Here is my code:

```
var xml:XML;
var list:XMLList;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
  xml = new XML(e.target.data);
  list = xml.Cube.Cube;
  trace(xml);
  trace(list);
}
```

The xml gets traced, but not the list. I followed the answer from that other question. I still don't see the list in the ouput window. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That xml includes namespaces and you skipped the namespace code that is in the answer that you referenced @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647356/using-forex-feed-from-xml-in-as3/14648024#14648024  This is a self-answering question ;-)

Comment: hi, thanks for answering . As I mentioned in the question. I did follow that answer which includes the namespace. It didn't work. Then I removed the namespace code with the above code. It didn't work either.

Comment: @DanishAjaib You should load your XML by calling `xmlLoader.load(url_request);` ...